# Django Chartjs outputs "No data" when data has value 0

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates, chart.js

I was trying to plot some Doughnut graphs with Django and chartJS. But stuck at a problem.
When the data has value = 0, I want the output in place of doughnut as "No data".

I researched for ngIf but the output is not as expected.
Here is my code

index.html

```
<div class="card-body card-body-cascade text-center"><div class="chartjs-size-monitor" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; overflow: hidden; pointer-events: none; visibility: hidden; z-index: -1;"><div class="chartjs-size-monitor-expand" style="position:absolute;left:0;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;overflow:hidden;pointer-events:none;visibility:hidden;z-index:-1;">
<div style="position:absolute;width:1000000px;height:1000000px;left:0;top:0"></div></div><div class="chartjs-size-monitor-shrink" style="position:absolute;left:0;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;overflow:hidden;pointer-events:none;visibility:hidden;z-index:-1;">
<div style="position:absolute;width:200%;height:200%;left:0; top:0"></div></div></div>
<canvas id="doughnutChart" height="250" width="730" class="chartjs-render-monitor" style="display: block; width: 408px; height: 272px;" ng-if="data.length <= 0"></canvas>
<span ng-if="data == 0">No data</span>
</div>
```

And the JS for doughnut is like this

```
<script>
chartIt();
    async function chartIt() {
    const data = await getData();
    var ctx = document.getElementById("doughnutChart").getContext('2d');
    var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'doughnut',
      data: {
        labels: ['d1','d2'],
        datasets: [{
          data: ['0','0'],
          backgroundColor: ["#F7464A", "#46BFBD", "#FDB45C", "#949FB1", "#4D5360"],
          hoverBackgroundColor: ["#FF5A5E", "#5AD3D1", "#FFC870", "#A8B3C5", "#616774"]
        }]
      },
      options: {
        responsive: true
      }
    });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Plugin Core API](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html#plugin-core-api) offers a range of hooks that may be used for performing custom code. You can use the `afterDraw` hook to write the text "No Data" directly on the canvas using [`CanvasRenderingContext2D`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D) in case the `sum` of all `data` values is zero.

Please take a look at your amended code and see how it works.

```js
new Chart('doughnutChart', {
  type: 'doughnut',
  plugins: [{
    afterDraw: function(chart) {
      let sum = chart.data.datasets[0].data.map(v => parseInt(v)).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
      if (sum == 0) {
        let width = chart.chart.width,
          height = chart.chart.height + 35,
          ctx = chart.chart.ctx;
        ctx.save();
        let fontSize = (height / 200).toFixed(2);
        ctx.font = fontSize + "em sans-serif";
        ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
        let text = 'No Data',
          textX = Math.round((width - ctx.measureText(text).width) / 2),
          textY = height / 2;
        ctx.fillText(text, textX, textY);
        ctx.restore();
      }
    }
  }],
  data: {
    labels: ['d1', 'd2'],
    datasets: [{
      data: ['0', '0'],
      backgroundColor: ["#F7464A", "#46BFBD", "#FDB45C", "#949FB1", "#4D5360"],
      hoverBackgroundColor: ["#FF5A5E", "#5AD3D1", "#FFC870", "#A8B3C5", "#616774"]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="doughnutChart" height="80"></canvas>
```